# dc.js add class to data points in multiple charts based on criteria from first chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dc.js

In a multi-chart dc.js/d3.js presentation, I wish to trap user click on a datapoint in the first chart, and:

1. identify all points in chart 1 with a value within 30 points of the clicked point; -- done
2. store the indices for these data points; -- done
3. colorize the stored datapoints in chart1; -- need help
4. colorize the points at same index locations in charts 2 and 3 -- need help

For example, user clicks on shift 2 on first chart. 140 cars were built on that shift. In chart 1, three shifts are within 30 of that shift's production: 2, 7, 10. I wish to make those 3 data points green, and then also make shifts 2, 7, 10 green in both charts 2 and 3 also. (Also, the original clicked-on datapoint should be red)

I am unsure how to add the greendot class to those three datapoints in the three charts.

[jsFiddle to work with](http://jsfiddle.net/zeLapnLe/2/)

```js
clearconsole();
var chartWidth = 500;
var myCSV = [ 
{"shift":"1","date":"01/01/2016/08/00/00","car":"178","truck":"125","bike":"317","moto":"237"},
{"shift":"2","date":"01/01/2016/17/00/00","car":"125","truck":"189","bike":"125","moto":"273"},
{"shift":"3","date":"02/01/2016/08/00/00","car":"140","truck":"219","bike":"328","moto":"1252"},
{"shift":"4","date":"02/01/2016/17/00/00","car":"222","truck":"290","bike":"432","moto":"378"},
{"shift":"5","date":"03/01/2016/08/00/00","car":"200","truck":"250","bike":"420","moto":"319"},
{"shift":"6","date":"03/01/2016/17/00/00","car":"230","truck":"220","bike":"310","moto":"413"},
{"shift":"7","date":"04/01/2016/08/00/00","car":"155","truck":"177","bike":"377","moto":"180"},
{"shift":"8","date":"04/01/2016/17/00/00","car":"179","truck":"203","bike":"405","moto":"222"},
{"shift":"9","date":"05/01/2016/08/00/00","car":"208","truck":"185","bike":"360","moto":"195"},
{"shift":"10","date":"05/01/2016/17/00/00","car":"150","truck":"290","bike":"315","moto":"280"},
{"shift":"11","date":"06/01/2016/08/00/00","car":"200","truck":"220","bike":"350","moto":"205"},
{"shift":"12","date":"06/01/2016/17/00/00","car":"230","truck":"170","bike":"390","moto":"400"},
];
console.log('Click on a datapoint in chart1 to begin ');

lc1 = dc.lineChart("#line1");
lc2 = dc.lineChart("#line2");
lc3 = dc.lineChart("#line3");

var dateFormat = d3.time.format("%d/%m/%Y/%H/%M/%S");

myCSV.forEach(function (d) {
 d.date = dateFormat.parse(d.date);
});

myCSV.forEach(function (d) {
 d['car'] = +d['car'];
 d['bike'] = +d['bike'];
 d['moto'] = +d['moto'];
});

//console.log(myCSV);

var facts = crossfilter(myCSV);
var dateDim = facts.dimension(function (d) {return d.date});

var carDim = facts.dimension(function (d) {return d['car']});
var dgCar = dateDim.group().reduceSum(function (d) {return d['car']});

var bikeDim = facts.dimension(function (d) {return d['bike']});
var dgBike = dateDim.group().reduceSum(function (d) {return d['bike']});

var motoDim = facts.dimension(function (d) {return d['moto']});
var dgMoto = dateDim.group().reduceSum(function (d) {return d['moto']});

var minDate = new Date ("2016-01-01T08:00:00.000Z");
var maxDate = new Date ("2016-01-06T17:00:00.000Z"); 

var maxY = d3.max(myCSV, function(d) {return d['car']});

lc1
.renderArea(false)
.width(chartWidth)
.height(250)
.dimension(dateDim)
.group(dgCar)
.defined(function(d) {if(d.y !==null) {return d.y;}})
.transitionDuration(1000)
.margins({top: 30, right: 20, bottom: 35, left: 60})
.yAxisLabel('Cars')
.renderHorizontalGridLines(true)
.brushOn(false)
.x(d3.time.scale().domain([minDate,maxDate]));
lc1.yAxis().ticks(5);
lc1.xAxis().ticks(3);

lc2
.renderArea(false)
.width(chartWidth)
.height(250)
.dimension(dateDim)
.group(dgBike)
.defined(function(d) {if(d.y !==null) {return d.y;}})
.transitionDuration(1000)
.margins({top: 30, right: 20, bottom: 35, left: 60})
.yAxisLabel('Bikes')
.renderHorizontalGridLines(true)
.brushOn(false)
.x(d3.time.scale().domain([minDate,maxDate]));
lc2.yAxis().ticks(5);
lc2.xAxis().ticks(3);

lc3
.renderArea(false)
.width(chartWidth)
.height(250)
.dimension(dateDim)
.group(dgMoto)
.defined(function(d) {if(d.y !==null) {return d.y;}})
.transitionDuration(1000)
.margins({top: 30, right: 20, bottom: 35, left: 60})
.yAxisLabel('Motos')
.renderHorizontalGridLines(true)
.brushOn(false)
.x(d3.time.scale().domain([minDate,maxDate]));
lc3.yAxis().ticks(5);
lc3.xAxis().ticks(3);


lc1.on('renderlet', function(lc1) {
console.log('myCSV.length: '+myCSV.length);
   var allDots1 = lc1.selectAll('circle.dot');
   var allDots2 = lc2.selectAll('circle.dot');
   var allDots3 = lc3.selectAll('circle.dot');
   allDots1.on('click', function(d,i) { //i==index, d==obj of clicked point
console.log(JSON.stringify(myCSV[i]));
      var arrWeeks = [];
      allDots1.filter((d,j)=> j===i).classed('reddot');
      for (var xx=0;xx<myCSV.length;xx++){
         var t1 = myCSV[xx].car - d.y;
         var t2 = d.y - myCSV[xx].car;
          var looptest = (t1<30 && t1>0) || (t2<30 && t2>0);
console.log(myCSV[xx].car +' (loop val) is/not within 30 of '+d.y+ '(clicked val)' + looptest);
     if ( (t1<30 && t1>0) || (t2<30 && t2>0) ){
           arrWeeks.push(xx); //All index points in "Cars" that are within 30 of clicked point
         }
          //Next line doesn't work:
     //allDots2.filter((d,j)=> j===xx).classed('greendot').style('fill-opacity', 1);
      }//ENDFOR
console.log("%s %o", 'arrWeeks: ', arrWeeks);
    /*
          Loop through all 3 "allDotsN" d3 collections and add
            greendot class to each circle that is at one of the 
            index values in arrWeeks. For example, if arrWeeks contains
            [2,4,6] then the 3rd, 5th and 7th dot points in all three
            graphs should be green (and the original clicked-on datapoint should be red)
        */
//      allDots1.filter((d,j)=> j===arrWeeks[]).classed('greendot').style('fill-opacity', 1);
//      allDots2.filter((d,j)=> j===arrWeeks[]).classed('greendot').style('fill-opacity', 1);
//      allDots3.filter((d,j)=> j===arrWeeks[]).classed('greendot').style('fill-opacity', 1);
   });//END allDots1.on(click);

});//END lc1.on(renderlet)

dc.renderAll();
dc.redrawAll();

function clearconsole(){
console.API;
if (typeof console._commandLineAPI !== 'undefined') {
    console.API = console._commandLineAPI; //chrome
} else if (typeof console._inspectorCommandLineAPI !== 'undefined') {
    console.API = console._inspectorCommandLineAPI; //Safari
} else if (typeof console.clear !== 'undefined') {
    console.API = console;
}
console.API.clear();
}
```

```css
svg{height:280px;width:500px;}

.greendot{stroke:green !important; fill:green !important; fill-opacity:1 !important;}

.reddot{stroke:red !important; fill:red !important; fill-opacity:1 !important;}
```

```html
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.3.3/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crossfilter/1.3.1/crossfilter.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/js/dc.js"></script>
<link href="http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/css/dc.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<svg id="line1"></svg>
<svg id="line2"></svg>
<svg id="line3"></svg>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `.classed('yourclass', true)`, see [docs](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/blob/master/README.md#selection_classed):

```
allDots1.on('click', function(d, i) { //i==index, d==obj of clicked point
    console.log(JSON.stringify(myCSV[i]));
    var arrWeeks = [i];

    for (var xx = 0; xx < myCSV.length; xx++) {
        var t1 = myCSV[xx].car - d.y;
        var t2 = d.y - myCSV[xx].car;
        var looptest = (t1 < 30 && t1 > 0) || (t2 < 30 && t2 > 0);
        console.log(myCSV[xx].car + ' (loop val) is/not within 30 of ' + d.y + '(clicked val)' + looptest);
        if ((t1 < 30 && t1 > 0) || (t2 < 30 && t2 > 0)) {
            arrWeeks.push(xx); //All index points in "Cars" that are within 30 of clicked point
        }
    } //ENDFOR
    console.log("%s %o", 'arrWeeks: ', arrWeeks);
    allDots1.classed('reddot', false);
    allDots1.classed('greendot', false);
    allDots2.classed('greendot', false);
    allDots3.classed('greendot', false);
    arrWeeks.forEach((i) => {
        allDots1.filter((d, j) => j === i).classed('greendot', true);
        allDots2.filter((d, j) => j === i).classed('greendot', true);
        allDots3.filter((d, j) => j === i).classed('greendot', true);
    });
    allDots1.filter((d, j) => j === i).classed('reddot', true);
});
```

[Working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zeLapnLe/5/)